# Do Azure websites go cold in Standard mode?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I just scaled my SHARED Azure websites to run in STANDARD mode on a small instance size scaled from 1 to 3 instances based on CPU. I've seen conflicting information about sites going cold in standard mode. Do I need to utilize endpoint monitoring to keep the site warm or will it always stay warm running in Standard mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your site is in STANDARD mode you can enable the **Always On** feature (in the portal under the CONFIGURATION tab) and your site (all instances of it) will always be up (warm).

Comment: Azure Web sites now have the Always On feature (see http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2014/01/16/windows-azure-staging-publishing-support-for-web-sites-monitoring-improvements-hyper-v-recovery-manager-ga-and-pci-compliance.aspx)

Comment: Any information on how configuring for Always On will affect hosting costs on Azure?

Comment: "Always On" feature has no affect on the cost, but it is only available on Standard mode websites.